# Query works fine in MySQL but not in PostgreSQL

Tags: mysql, postgresql

This query is working fine in MySQL but not in PostgreSQL:

```
select
concat(hc.id, hl.languagecode) AS id,
hc.id AS category_id,
hl.languagecode AS languagecode
from language hl
join category hc
left join categorytranslation hct ON hl.languagecode = hct.languagecode and hc.id = hct.category_id;
```

In PostgreSQL I got sometimes the error:

> ERROR:  syntax error at end of input LINE 9: ....languagecode =
>   hct.languagecode and hc.id = hct.category_id
>                                                                          ^ Query failed PostgreSQL said: syntax error at end of input

Or an empty result.
I am using Postico to test it.

What is wrong with it?

What I want to do is get the result of this:

```
 select
        concat(hc.id, hl.languagecode) AS id,
        hc.id AS category_id,
        hl.languagecode AS languagecode,
        hc.slug AS slug
from category hc, language hl
```

But I also want to join a table with translations 'categorytranslation'. If a translation is available that should be taken instead of 'category' table. For that I have modified the query like this:

```
    SELECT
            concat(hp.id, hl.languagecode) AS id,
            hp.id AS id,
            hl.languagecode AS languagecode,
            hpt.languagecode as translang,
            CASE WHEN (hpt.languagecode is not null and hpt.slug is not null and trim(hpt.slug) <> '')
              THEN hpt.slug
              ELSE hp.slug
            END AS slug,
    from language hl
join category hc
left join categorytranslation hct ON hl.languagecode = hct.languagecode and hc.id = hct.category_id;
```

Comment: The join condition looks a bit strange, as you are doing a cross join between the `language` and `category` tables.  Is this correct?

Answer (score 0):

In PostgreSQL every join requires a join condition phrase. In your query the relationships between the tables appear to be `hl -> hct -> hc`; the query then becomes:

```
SELECT hc.id || languagecode AS id,
       hc.id AS category_id,
       languagecode
FROM language hl
LEFT JOIN hapis_hatracocategorytranslation hct USING (languagecode)
JOIN category hc ON hc.id = hct.category_id;
```

Note that by using the `USING` phrase in the first join condition there is no ambiguity between the `languagecode` columns from both tables so you can omit the alias in the select list.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.

It works so far, but the result returns results only for one 'languagecode'. The table 'language' contains 5 languages.
The fields are: id, active, languagecode